# Service don't start after boot

Tags: android, service, bootcompleted

I have a service in my Android app that works perfectly if i started manually, but i need that service to start on boot, and i can't get it started automatically after rebooting the phone, i tryed several tutorials but nothing works.

Here is my manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tvshowsguide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application

    <service android:name="androidservice.SyncService" />

    <receiver android:name="androidservice.SyncAuto" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the BroadcastReceiver code:

```
public class SyncAuto extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent SyncService = new Intent(context, SyncService.class).setAction(SRVC);
            context.startService(SyncService);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run an Activity in the app at least once?  If not it won't start as a security feature.  It may also have issues if its on the SD card rather than internal memory, because this event is broadcast before the SD card is mounted.

Comment: Yes, I install the app, run the main activity, then start the service, and then I reboot, once rebooted i check if the service has started and it's not.

With the problem you said about the SD card, you thinc it is better if the app is installed on the internal memory?

Thank you Gabe Sechan

Comment: Your service and receiver names are wrong. They should start with a . or have the full name of the application. You should change it to `.androidservice.SyncAuto` and try.

Comment: Mr Gabe Sechan your solution about the SDcard it worked perfectly!! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem must be the reference of your service, since you have an application with

```
 package="com.tvshowsguide"
```

Your service and receiver must have a name like:

```
 <service android:name="com.tvshowsguide.androidservice.SyncService" />
 <receiver android:name="com.tvshowsguide.androidservice.SyncAuto" >
```